# PowerShell - Remote Start-Process - "This command cannot be run due to the error: This operation requires an interactive window station."

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, testcomplete

I am trying to start SmartBear's TestExecute program remotely through PowerShell and I'm getting an error when trying to call `Start-Process`.

> This command cannot be run due to the error: The requested operation requires elevation.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
>       + PSComputerName        : myClient.ourDomain.local

I can't figure out how to get around this. How do I make this work?

Here's my script:

```
#  $TestExecuteLocalSource is the directory of TestExecute.exe on the remote machine
#  $TestProjectSuite is the directory of project suite on the remote machine
#  These paths are local (relative to the remote machine)

Function StartTestExecute
{        
    $rs = Get-PSSession

    $script = {param($TestExecuteLocalSource, $TestProjectSuite);

        cd $TestExecuteLocalSource    
        Start-Process .\TestExecute.exe -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList $TestProjectSuite, '/r', '/p:eSignRegression', '/e'
    } 

    Invoke-Command -Session $rs -ScriptBlock $script -ArgumentList ($TestExecuteLocalSource, $TestProjectSuite)
```

Answer (score 0):

When running tests, TestComplete/TestExecute must have access to the system GUI. When you are running test on a remote machine using this approach, GUI is not accessible and TestExecute cannot work. The best way to run a test remotely is using the [Network Suite](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/55046/) feature of TestComplete. It will automatically create a GUI session on a remote machine and run the test within it.